# What's the Noether charge associated with Kaehler invariance of SuGra?

Tags: research-level, supersymmetry, symmetry, noethers-theorem, supergravity

What is the Noether charge associated with Kahler invariance of [supergravity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity) (SUGRA)? As the question is rather tangential to what I need to do, I have not tried explicitly calculating it myself, but I'm sure that I'm not the first one to wonder.

Comment: Found [this](http://books.google.fr/books?id=7ANrOHJLTjMC&pg=PA378&dq=supergravity+freedman+VAN+PROEYEN+%22In+supergravity+a+similar+situation+occurs%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=0g-FUtzkNKnO0QXz2IHwCg&ved=0CDMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=supergravity%20freedman%20VAN%20PROEYEN%20%22In%20supergravity%20a%20similar%20situation%20occurs%22&f=false) Chapter 17A.2, p 378, in  Freedman/ Van Proeyen Supergravity book. This is about Kahler-Hodge manifolds (apparently linked to matter-coupled N=1 supergravity),"Kahler charges" apply to fermions only, and are (like magnetic monopoles), multiple of a minimum charge.

Comment: @Trimok thank you for the reference. I looked it up and it was informative, but did not directly relate to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer: There is none.

The issue at hand is that the Kaehler invariance is just that - an invariance, not a continuous symmetry of the fields. Most prominently the superpotential must transform as
$$ \mathcal W \to \mathcal W e^{-h} $$
A general superpotential that leads to consistent theories is
$$ \mathcal W =\frac{1}{2} m_{ab} \phi^a \phi^b + \frac{1}{3} Y_{abc} \phi^a \phi^b \phi^c $$
with at least one of the $m_{ab}$ **and** $Y_{abc}$ non-zero. From this is is obvious, that no transformation of the *fields* $\phi^a$ exists, such that $\mathcal W \to \mathcal W e^{-h}$ without redefining the couplings.

Thus, there is a Kaehler invariance, which involves a redefinition of the couplings and has its value on its own (e.g. on non-simply connected internal spaces, the Kaehler potential might only be defined locally, with definitions on different charts being equal up to Kaehler transformations $\mathcal K' = \mathcal K + f(\phi) + \bar f(\bar\phi)$), but this is not a *symmetry* in the sense of Noether's theorem.